# How to use Tridion 2011 SP1 Java program on SDL Web 8?

Tags: web8, broker, upgrade

I'm installing SDL Web 8, and migrating Java Tag Libraries which have been used on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1, those Tag Libraries are using Broker API.

I set up Java Web appliation following "Installing the API (RESTful) Server Role" in SDL Web 8's manual.
So I copied all JAR files in `Content Delivery\roles\api\rest\java\lib` folder in installation media to `lib` direcory.

But following error occures at requesting the Web application.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.broker.querying.filter.ResultFilter

I saw a documentation "SDL Web 8 Content Delivery API (Java)", but there is indeed an interface `com.tridion.broker.querying.filter.ResultFilter`.

Why does `ClassNotFoundException` occurs even though the classes is on API reference?

Are there any JAR files required?

If Tridion 2011 SP1's Broker API used, is it possible to use it on Web 8? 
Or Should I use "in-process" modules instead of "rest" to use legacy API, as described in "Installing the legacy API (in-process) Server Role"?

Comment: I recall something along the lines of a recompile being required because some Classes changed to an Interface, could it be that the code which uses `com.tridion.broker.querying.filter.ResultFilter` is not using it as an interface?

Comment: I investigated Java source code in detail, "ResultFilter" seems no problem. But I found some other problems. I write about them in following new post.http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15334/problems-about-migrating-javabroker-api-from-tridion-2011-sp1-to-sdl-web-8

Comment: Why a new question, you could have edited this one. If this one is no longer relevant, please close it.